# Is there a list of all keywords used in structural search and replace?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

Recently I've needed to use something more powerful than *refactoring using regexes*. IntelliJ Idea has [structural search and replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html) and some [examples](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html#) but I didn't manage to find a list of all keywords that can be used in SSR. While typing in SSR fields, I see some suggestions from different libraries and it's not clear what can be used and what cannot.

Is there any list of all keywords that can be used in SSR (it's be super handy if there are not only keywords but also their explanations)?

Answer (score 2):

## Variable names exist on a per-template basis

There is no repository of variable names. You will have to define variable names which describe what you're looking for, then set the constraints according to your needs.

You can do this by clicking the "Edit Variables.." button that appears below the template. You'll also be able to view the existing variables for that template (and their constraints).

From the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/search-templates.html):

> When you construct a pattern for a structural search you are basically writing a script. To simplify your scripting process, IntelliJ IDEA offers you a list of predefined **search templates that you can use as prototypes for your search pattern.**

---

**Using Existing Template**

If we took the template for "all methods of the class (within the hierarchy)":

[image]

Used it to search the following class:

```
class Scratch {
    public void demo() {

    }
}
```

We get the following results:

[image]

---

**Using custom template which emulates existing template**

If I change up the names & fix the constraints:

[image]
[image]

We get the same results:

[image]

---

**PS:** I used `\w*` as a constraint for `$MyMethodName$` as the existing template did not have that field filled in. However, that field must contain a value in order to check the box `Apply constraint within type hierarchy`. I'm not sure what would be the preferred way to achieve this, as the existing template seems to "break the rules" in this aspect.

Comment: I believe you have an old version of Idea (according to your screenshots), the UI for editing variables has changed.

It's clear how to experiment, find and edit the correct template but I believe things could be done faster if we have full list of variables. :)

Comment: @ArtemKrosheninnikov Yes, I'm still on 2018 hahaha, hasn't failed me yet (until now..). It seems on 2020, you move the mouse cursor caret to whivhever variable you want to view/modify. Filters should appear in a text pane to the right: "*You can edit the existing filters or add new conditions, for example, add some regular expressions, or a script constraint. Place the caret at the code variable and use the filter area to manage filters.*". I agree that a list of variables would be useful. Maybe they didn't want potential namespace bloat, since the feature isn't only for Java? Just a guess.